# pyspotify Segmentation Fault (libspotify)

Tags: python, python-2.7, spotify

I am trying to work with pyspotify with but no luck.

Setup:

- Ubuntu - 12.04 TLS - fresh(ish) install
- virtualenv - 1.8.2
- libspotify - 12.1.51
- pyspotiy - dev (1.8)

I have the pyspotify example `jukebox.py` but when I run it it always gives Segmentation Fault

*(I had this example was working on a separate VM before however need to replicate the functionality on a fresh VM.)*

```
$ python jukebox.py -uEMAIL_ADDRESS -pPASSWORD
Logging in, please wait...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The `spotify_appkey.key` is in the same folder (it doesn't get as far as the SegFault without the key).

Additionally I created a script to simply connect to Spotify but this also gives a Segmentation Fault.

from spotify.manager import

```
from spotify import SpotifySessionManager

session = SpotifySessionManager(username=EMAIL_ADDRESS, password=PASSWORD)

print('Connecting')
session.connect()
print('Connected')
```

This also give:

```
$ python test.py
Session created
Connecting
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Do you get the same effect when you execute the library naively i.e. without the wrapper?

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't know how to use libspotify on it's own.  I need to use some of its functionality in a Django project so looked to pyspotify as a wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run `jukebox.py` as root.

Comment: Unfortunately root didn't help.
Eventually I ended up using https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server#spotify-api-server instead.